# Blob storage in parse sdk

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

Can I store blob files in parse collection as if in mysql. I found out That we can upload file to parse and save the url with in collection. But I am thinking of storing blob in the record itself. Can i save it to parse collection

Answer (score 1):

Q- Can I store blob files in parse collection as if in mysql?
A- **No**. But you can save the files on parse, in return for the image, it'll give you `direct link (URL)` and `name` for the image that you have uploaded. Normally that's all that anyone requires.

If you want to look for how to save `files` on parse, see these links:

[Parse.File](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.File.html)

And

[Upload files via Ajax (Javascript)](https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api)

Comment: Hi Ravi, I am aware of the way u suggested ie, uploading an image and getting url to save with in collection. Any how Thanks a lot for your answer